# workbook.getTheme().getThemeColor(bgColor.getIndex()) is returning null/wrong color references

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, xssf

I solved it with an ugly workaround:

Does somebody else know a better solution?

```
public static BaseColor getIndexedColor(XSSFWorkbook wb, short idx) {
    byte[] rgb = wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().getColors().getIndexedColors().getRgbColorList().get(idx).getRgb();
    BaseColor myColor = ExcelToPDF.getBaseColorFromRGB(rgb);
    return myColor;
}

public static BaseColor getBaseColorFromRGB(byte[] rgb) {

    if (rgb == null) {
       return new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
    }

    int r = (rgb[1] < 0) ? (rgb[1] + 256) : rgb[1];
    int g = (rgb[2] < 0) ? (rgb[2] + 256) : rgb[2];
    int b = (rgb[3] < 0) ? (rgb[3] + 256) : rgb[3];

    return new BaseColor(r, g, b);
}
```

also had to add in my pom.xml a reference to ooxml-schemas 1.1 because CTColors is missing from the current version of poi-ooxml-schemas (14)

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why do you think you need to be messing around with theme indexes at all?

Comment: Needed a functionality to export excel documents in pdf. The excel documents are created also dynamic. The project I work on requires both excel and pdf output for a document. I'm using apache poi for creating excel documents and iText for PDF files. 
getIndexedColor receive the index of excel cell color and create/returns coresponding BaseColor for iText.

Comment: But why are you messing around with the low level CT classes? Why not just get a [XSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html) off a style or font, and get the RGB / ARGB off that?

Comment: Because, like I said in the title, the getARGB() returns wrong color. Also the hex code of color retuned is wrong. Tryed also take the indexed color from Themes but again the color is wrong. And is more... some indexes returns nul. After diging 2 days, found that ugly workarond.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest (3.15 final), what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Tryed all versions from 3.9 to 3.15 vith the same result

Comment: To be more specific, I have some excel templates that at runtime are filled with data and then delivered in excel or pdf. I created the templates using Numbers on a Mac and expoted to excel. Could this be a reason?